# -webkit-tap- on select dropdown?

Tags: html, css

**Problem**:
    I have implemented a standard drop-down using html. I modified it with no borders using css. When i tap on the drop-down to change the choice, i am getting orange color line around the drop-down.

**Try**

```
select
{
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);    
   -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only;
   -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

I tried all the above one by one. But it is not working>

**Expected solution**

Orange color border shouldn't be shown when i tap on my drop-down.

**Browser:** Nexus-Chrome

Any suggestions>

Comment: Try and replicate the issue using jsfiddle.net (or something similar) or post your code

Comment: I don't know how to show android specific issues in js fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without any code it's hard to tell but I imagine

```
select
{
    outline: none;
}
```

or

```
select:focus
{
    outline: none;
}
```

will do the trick for you. I'm guessing the orange border is added by chrome.